# Expandable custom- UITableViewCell from NIB

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to create expandable-cell form nib. It looks fine if dimenssions of cell in my tableview are equal to the dimensions of custom-cell nib. But when i'm trying to change height of custom cell to make it smaller it looks like this:

[image]

Can you give me some advices how can i make expand/collapse custom table cell from nib and avoid this effect?

UPD: I have heightForRowAtIndexPath implemented and it works fine. The base problem that all outlets that should be visible only when the cell is expanded are visible over all tableview    for all cells when there are collapsed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution and it's very simple. I just need to set "Clip SubViews" property of my custom-cell in the Interface Builder.

Comment: Very simple hint  for expand the table view.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [heightForRowAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a) datasourse method. It can be looking like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (expandableCell)
        return 20.0f;
    return 44.0f;
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but you'll also have to call [tableView reloadCellAtIndexPath:...] on the table when you expand/contract a cell, otherwise it won't call the heightForRowAtIndexPath method again. One way to do that is to broadcast an NSNotification from your cell when you expand/contract it and pick it up in the table's view controller so that it knows that the cell needs reloading.

Comment: @NickLockwood, yes you are correct. But OP mean only this issue, and reloading table looks like another question. Maybe OP solved it, maybe  asked it in another thread :)

Comment: I have heightForRowAtIndexPath implemented and it works fine, the base problem that all outlets from table-cell nib has been placed over the table-view after ViewDidLoad

Comment: @stalk, check autoresizng mask for you outlets.

Comment: the main case is that outlets shouldn't be autoresizable, when cell is collapsed it should looks like cell at row0 and row1 at the screenshot, and some oulets should be shown only after expanding. But in my situation I have all outlets  over the table-view